# Is it possible to do IR spectrometry with emitter and photoresistor on the same side?

Tags: spectroscopy

When doing spectrophotometry, there is generally a light source that emits the light that then passes trough whatever you want to measure, and then on the other side, a photoresistor that can sense how much of the light has been absorbed.

But is there any way the sensor and the emitter could be on the same side ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - put a mirror on the other side of the sample and bounce the beam back towards source